# How do I make Vim aware of the Java 8 lambda syntax?

Tags: java, vim

The Java syntax file that comes with Vim 7.4 is choking on the Java 8 lambda syntax. It highlights the `->` red. How can I fix this?

Comment: See http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/1905/vims-syntax-highlighting-considers-a-lambda-in-java-an-error .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a file in `~/.vim/after/syntax` named `java.vim` and add the following to this file:

```
syn clear javaError
syn match javaError "<<<\|\.\.\|=>\|||=\|&&=\|\*\/"
syn match javaFuncDef "[^-]->"
```

The second line is copied from the standard java syntax file, but without

```
[^-]->
```

For more about the `~/.vim/after/` directory, see `:help after-directory`.

Comment: You might want to change it to this, so you don't accidentally try to use const as an identifier. `syn match javaError "<<<\|\.\.\|=>\|||=\|&&=\|\*\/\|goto\|const"`

Comment: Thanks! This works for the diamond (`<>`) too. By the way, you should probably accept your answer.

Comment: You're welcome! Great to hear. Any particular reason to accept own answers? To communicate that more answers are not needed?